# Compiler doesn't show any errors or warnings but the program doesn't work

Tags: c, pointers, gcc, compiler-errors, compiler-warnings

I tried to build and run the following program, but it breaks down executing. I thought maybe I made a mistake but 0 errors and 0 warnings were shown.

After researching such behavior on stackoverflow, I mostly saw some misplaced semicolons or forgotten address-operators, which I do not see in this source code or am I overlooking something?
Could some C or GCC Guru tell me what is wrong and why?

Operating system is Windows 7, and compiler had enabled:
-pedantic -w -Wextra -Wall -ansi

Here is the source code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

char *split(char * wort, char c)
{
    int i = 0;
    while (wort[i] != c && wort[i] != '\0') {
        ++i;
    }
    if (wort[i] == c) {
        wort[i] = '\0';
        return &wort[i+1];
    } else {
        return NULL;
    }
}


int main()
{
    char *in = "Some text here";
    char *rest;
    rest = split(in,' ');
    if (rest == NULL) {
        printf("\nString could not be devided!");
        return 1;
    }
    printf("\nErster Teil: ");
    puts(in);
    printf("\nRest: ");
    puts(rest);
    return 0;
}
```

The expected behavior is that the string "Some text here" is split at its first space ' ' and the expected output would be:

```
Erster Teil: Some

Rest: text here
```

Comment: `char* in = "Some text here";` does not allocate memory for your string. It only allocates the memory to hold the char pointer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are modifying a string literal, that's undefined behavior. Change this

```
char* in = "Some text here";
```

to

```
char in[] = "Some text here";
```

This makes `in` an array and initializes it with `"Some text here"`. You should use `const` to prevent accidentally having this bug when you define a  pointer to a string literal.

Comment: Ok, but isn' t the declaration "char * in" and "char in[ ]" äquivalent in C and then why does one wok and the other does not?

Comment: No, the first one declares a pointer the second one an array. The array and the string literal `"Some text here"` are not the same object, the array is modifiable the string literal isn't. The first definition, makes a pointer to the string literal so when you modify it you are actually modifying the string literal itself. As a function paramter, the array is always converted to a pointer if that's what you mean.

Comment: Ah ok, last question:What would I need to change or add in the code so it works with "char * in"?

Comment: You would need to copy the string literal, include *string.h* and try `char *in = strdup("Some text here"); if (in == NULL) return -1; /* Do whatever you can with in */ free(in);`

Comment: Or you could `char array[] = "Some text here"; char *in = array;`.

Comment: @dima: Read about [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior). Compile with `gcc -Wall -Wextra -g`. **Use the debugger** (`gdb`) & [valgrind](http://valgrind.org/)